# How to preserve relevance order of cts:search results

Tags: marklogic, relevance, cts-search

I have the following codes:

1)

```
for $song in cts:search(fn:doc(), "night")
return $song/ts:top-song/ts:title/text()
```

2)

```
cts:search(fn:doc(), "night")/ts:top-song/ts:title/text()
```

cts:search returns documents as per the relevance.
Both the codes, return results in a different order.
Which would return the result with the correct relevance and why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first.

In the second, XPath is applied to the entire sequence returned by cts:search, but as per XPath standard the result of that is re-ordered into document-order, which becomes unpredictable when the nodes in the sequence come from different documents.

The first applies a FLWOR iteration on the sequence, which ensures keeping the order, and the XPath is applied to each item in the sequence separately.

HTH!

Comment: Yes, That brings a lot of clarity. Thanks